# Cannot use a scalar value as an array (was actually me trying to access array key not existing)

Tags: php, arrays

I updated the question title since the error I wish I would have been getting was "you are trying to access a key that doesn't exist", on eof you commenters led me to see that. Anyways, here's my original question:

I keep getting the error

> Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in...

From the second line below. `getContainerSleepSettings()` returns an array but that shouldn't be a problem should it?

```
   $helper = $this->get('biztv.helper.globalHelper');
    $containers = $helper->getContainers();

    //setup helper array with id's corresponding to the $containers (array of container entities)
    $containerHelper = array();
    foreach ($containers as $c) {
        $containerHelper[] = $c->getId();

        //Find out if sleeping
        $sleepSettings = $this->getContainerSleepSettings($c);
        var_dump( $containerHelper[$c->getId()]['wakeup'] = $sleepSettings['wakeup_s'] );
        var_dump( $containerHelper[$c->getId()]['sleep_s'] = $sleepSettings['sleep_s'] );

        if ( $sleepSettings['wakeup'] < date('U') && date('U') < $sleepSettings['sleep'] ) {
            $containerHelper[$c->getId()]['asleep'] = true; 
        }

        //Find out if online
        //$containerHelper[$c->getId()]['online'] = '$this->getOnlineAction( $c->getId() )';


        //find out if inherit layout/content



        //Find out if container receives mediasync



    }

    print_r($containerHelper);
    die;


private function getContainerSleepSettings($container) {

    //First find a container with sleepSettings
    while(!$container->getHourEnd() || !$container->getHourStart() ) {

        if ( $container->getParent() ) {
            $container = $container->getParent();
        }
        else {
            return null; //Infinity limited by level of parents - once no more parents we return null.
        }
    }

    //If we did find a parent with sleepSettings on it:


    $sleep['wakeup'] = $container->getHourEnd();
    $sleep['sleep'] = $container->getHourStart();

    if ($sleep['wakeup']) {
        $sleep['wakeup_s'] = $sleep['wakeup']->format('H:i');
    }
    else {
        $sleep['wakeup_s'] = '-';
    }


    if ($sleep['sleep']) {
        $sleep['sleep_s'] = $sleep['sleep']->format('H:i');
    }
    else {
        $sleep['sleep_s'] = '-';
    }

    return $sleep;          

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

before accessing the values out of the return value you need to check if it is an array or not..

```
$sleepSettings = $this->getContainerSleepSettings($c);
if ( is_array($sleepSettings) ) {
    var_dump( $containerHelper[$c->getId()]['wakeup'] = $sleepSettings['wakeup_s'] );
    var_dump( $containerHelper[$c->getId()]['sleep_s'] = $sleepSettings['sleep_s'] );

    if ( $sleepSettings['wakeup'] < date('U') && date('U') < $sleepSettings['sleep'] ) {
        $containerHelper[$c->getId()]['asleep'] = true; 
    }
} else {
   // $sleepSettings  is null
   // do something else..
}
```

Comment: can I not have null in my array?

Comment: yes you can but when it returns null and you trying to access any key you wont get that key and it will trigger the message `Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in`

Comment: actually you need to indicate at what line you get this error?

Comment: thanks. added a condition:    if ($sleepSettings <> null) {
    $containerHelper[$c->getId()]['wakeup'] = $sleepSettings['wakeup_s'];
    $containerHelper[$c->getId()]['sleep_s'] = $sleepSettings['sleep_s'];
   }

Answer (score 0):

```
$sleep = array();
$sleep['wakeup'] = $container->getHourEnd();
```